# Cocos2d-x setScaleX()

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

So I was programming a game in cocos2d-x and I need one of the sprites to get wider for a certain amount of time, so I tried with the method setScaleX(). The problem is that the content size of the sprite does not actually change, and since my collision system is based on the content size of the sprite, they do not properly work. Here is the code I use for scaling:

```
bar = Sprite::create( "Bar.png" );
CCLOG("Size: %f,%f.", bar->getContentSize().width, bar->getContentSize().height);
bar->setScaleX(1.5);
CCLOG("Size: %f,%f.", bar->getContentSize().width, bar->getContentSize().height);
```

The output is exactly the same on both cases. Is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

`ContentSize` represent the original texture size unless you set it using `setContentSize` method.

You can either multiply size with scale factor or use `boundingBox().size` to know about current size of scaled sprite(if not rotated or skewed).

Answer (score 1):

```
cocos2d::Size size1 = cocos2d::CCDirector::getInstance()->getWinSize();
scaleX=size1.width/768;
scaleY=size1.height/1024;

Sprite *sp1=Sprite::create("01.png");
    sp1->setScaleX(scaleX);
    sp1->setScaleY(scaleY);
    this->addChild(sp1);
```

Comment: a little explaination will be higly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Scale for Landscape:

cocos2d::Size size = cocos2d::CCDirector::getInstance()->getWinSize();
scaleX=size.width/1024;
scaleY=size.height/768;

Scale for Portrait:

cocos2d::Size size = cocos2d::CCDirector::getInstance()->getWinSize();
scaleX=size.width/768;
scaleY=size.height/1024;

Sprite *sp=Sprite::create("01.png");
    sp->setScaleX(scaleX);
    sp->setScaleY(scaleY);
    this->addChild(sp);
```